# Arduino Code Not Processing Serial Output

Tags: c, arduino

I am using a Arduino Uno for an embedded systems course. My assignment is that I have to write a function that implements these specifications. Take an input from the user (‘R’, ‘G’, ‘B’) and display Red, Green or Blue. The function name must be dispColor(), the input must be char a and their is no return. My code is below, however whenever I type in an input I receive no output. Where is the error in my code?

```
String dispColor(char){

  char a = Serial.read();

  if (a == "R")
    Serial.print("Red");
  else if (a == "G")
    Serial.print("Green");
  else if (a == "B")
    Serial.print("Blue");

}

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  String dispColor();
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

My Updated code

```
void dispColor(char a){
  if(Serial.available()){
        a = Serial.read();
        if(a == 'R')
        Serial.print("Red");
        else if(a == 'G')
        Serial.print("Green");
        else if(a == 'B')
        Serial.print("Blue");
    }
  }

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);   
    Serial.println("Please type in R, G, or B.");
    dispColor();
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Have you initialized Serial to begin with? If you did, are you sure you opened Serial in the same baudrate?

Comment: Use double quotes for strings e.g. `"Red"`. Use single quotes for single characters, e.g. `if (a == 'R')`

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli Yes, in the setup function.

Comment: Then it is as @user3386109 said. You dont compare strings, in a way you did. Using single quotes will solve the problem. If you want to compare strings, use `strcmp` function

Comment: @user3386109 I changed the double quotes in the if statement comparison to single quotes. Still no output.

Comment: Oh. You have used your function in setup. So, it tries to read Serial only once and at that time, you do not enter any input. Try calling function in loop.

Comment: Moreover, you wrote function as follows: function takes an argument of type char and returns a String. However, as you mentioned, function should not return anything so it should be void. Moreover, you should read Serial in loop and call that function while passing read charachter

Answer (score 1):

As says the comment in `setup` ("// put your setup code here, to **run once**:", that code will be executed only once, so when you're ready to "type an input", there will not be any code running to read it.

Thus, one thing you'll definitely need to do is move  `dispColor` to `loop`.

There are a few more mistakes:

- You're comparing a char with a String
- You should be passing a parameter to `dispColor`, not reading from within it
- You should probably only be calling `dispColor` if there's input available.

Have a look at https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/ to get started!

Comment: Please edit your question and **add** a new section with your updated code (don't modify the original code).

Comment: I've added another section with the updated the code.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've addressed any of the points I listed, but only added a check for whether a signal was available on the serial port. Please change your code to incorporate the points mentioned and post an update. If you don't understand something, feel free to ask specific questions!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

My new code

```
void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);   
Serial.println("Please type in R, G, or B.");  
}

void dispColor(char a)
{
while(!Serial.available());
a = Serial.read();
 if(a == 'R')
    Serial.println("Red");
      else if(a == 'G')
    Serial.println("Green");
      else if(a == 'B')
    Serial.println("Blue");
    Serial.print('\n');
}

void loop() {
char a;
dispColor(a);

}
```

Comment: One thing that remains: you should read from `Serial` in `loop` and pass that as to `dispColor` - at the m.j moment you're ignoring (overwriting) the parameter `a` in `dispColor`.